# Fix a dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I've been trying since this weekend implement this but no success so far.

I have a dropdown that should display items available on every event.

```
            "id": "80773bce-7baf-49ae-8e65-328064a97116",
            "title": "Sed sit qui enim corrupti magni at et voluptatum atque.",
            "address": "69706 Lester Drive, Bedfordshire, Wilmington",
            "guests": 70,
            "budget": "65947.00",
            "created_at": "2022-03-21T21:37:27.700+00:00",
            "updated_at": "2022-03-21T21:37:27.700+00:00",
            "is_public": false,
            "description": "Fuga illo amet. Nihil omnis quae inventore repudiandae iure excepturi. Sunt necessitatibus harum culpa aliquid asperiores tenetur. Rem doloribus minus beatae officiis. Reprehenderit iure consequatur ea voluptates itaque voluptate vel dolorem reiciendis. Illo omnis et.\n \rDicta magnam et architecto ex cumque. Fugiat velit ullam deserunt perferendis consequuntur libero excepturi illum aspernatur. Quo iure libero vitae voluptatem aliquid qui dolores perspiciatis. Sed libero iusto ea odit incidunt iste libero.",
            "event_date": "2022-03-21",
            "start_hour": "2022-03-21T10:26:06.000Z",
            "end_hour": "2022-03-21T10:26:06.000Z",
            "landmark": "-11.9522,179.1757",
            "location": "Laudantium veritatis animi ut quo est dolor inventore voluptate iure.",
            "customer": null,
            "eventType": null,
            "items": [
                {
                    "id": "70d32cee-a0fc-458a-b3e0-1bd0dbd4fdb5",
                    "title": "Sunt et unde eaque.",
                    "description": "Aut fugit voluptas explicabo animi. Illum reiciendis saepe minima dolore saepe pariatur omnis et et. Qui ratione rerum voluptatem voluptatem natus voluptatem eligendi. Iure sint et quae cumque sit neque. Similique magnam reprehenderit.",
                    "order": 97,
                    "enabled": true,
                    "created_at": "2022-03-21T21:37:27.702+00:00",
                    "updated_at": "2022-03-21T21:37:27.702+00:00"
                }
            ],
            "county": null
        },
```

This should be the return from API.
Data is an array of objects and I must display all it's items under "eventType" line.
When I display it I must select one option and then should return only events that has that item on it's service.

So far, what I did was:

```
const mappedEventsData = eventsData.map((item) => {
    return item.items[0];
  });
```

And I succesfully rendered those . Then I passed it's title or id as paramater and my state is ok with that.

When I try to filter it however I cannot do it. I tried to console.log

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
    getEventsData();
    console.log(mappedEventsData.includes(searchByTitle));
  }, [searchByTitle]);
```

```
{mappedEventsData
                      .filter((item) => {
                        if (!item) return false;
                        return item.title.toLowerCase();
                      })
                      // .filter((item, index) => index < 3)
                      ?.map((item) => {
                        return (
                          <option onClick={() => handleChangeSearchByEvents(item.id)} key={item.id}>
                            {item.title}
                          </option>
                        );
                      })}
```

and it always returns false.

How can I fix it and make it work?

Comment: I'm unsure what it is you are attempting to do with your filter. What does the desired output look like?

Comment: I'm sorry if didn't made myself clear.
So, I have the array of DATA this array of DATA has a bunch of objects and inside of EACH object has an array of ITEMS.

I must display those ITEMS in a <selct><option> which is OK so far as I posted above.

When I click on some ITEM I should be able to filter that Item to find any other event with the same Item.